# C# - Call overridden method only in sub-class

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to solve the following OO problem. I know it smells a bit, but I have to adapt to an existing design. Consider the following snippet:

```
class Parent
{
   public virtual Context GetContext()
   {
       return new Context(true);
   }

   public virtual GetData()
   {
       var context = GetContext();
       var result = Query(context);
       return result;
   }

   public string GetData2()
   {
       var context = GetContext();
       var result = Query(context);
       return result;
   }

}

class Child : Parent
{
   public override Context GetContext()
   {
       return new Context(false);
   }

   public override GetData()
   {
       var context = GetContext();
       var result = Query(context);
   }
}
```

I would like the following result:

```
new Parent().GetData() => would call Parent.GetContext();
new Parent().GetData2() => would call Parent.GetContext();
new Child().GetData() => would call Child.GetContext();
new Child().GetData2() (not overriden in Child) => would call Parent.GetContext();
```

The actual result is:

```
new Parent().GetData() => calls Parent.GetContext();
new Parent().GetData2() => calls Parent.GetContext();
new Child().GetData() => calls Child.GetContext();
new Child().GetData2() => calls Child.GetContext();
```

Comment: And what is the result that you get, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: And the problem is......?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the default behaviour (no `virtual`) already does, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Ok, the problem is at `GetData2`, the only solution is to override `GetData2` and call `base.GetContext`

Comment: Added the actual result to clarify, thanks.

Comment: take virtual off parent.getcontext

Comment: Wait, do the Parent and Child class do have a parent-child relationship, or is Child rather inheriting from Parent (that means Child **is a** Parent) intentional?

Comment: Parent provides CleanupRoomAndGetCookie(), child decides for himself and calls PlayVideoGame() instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override (replace in this case) the GetData2 function:

```
    class Child : Parent
    {
       public override Context GetContext()
       {
           return new Context(false);
       }

       public override GetData()
       {
           var context = GetContext();
           var result = Query(context);
       }

       public new string GetData2()
       {
           var context = base.GetContext();
           return Query(context);
       }
    }
```

Remember that using the new modifier does not override the base function, if replaces it, this means that if you cast a `Child` as `Parent` and you call `GetData2` it will call the old function and not the new replaced one.

Comment: Mandatory warning about the pitfalls of the `new` modifier could be helpful, i guess (i.e., `Child x = new Child(); x.GetData2();` vs. `Parent x = new Child(); x.GetData2();`)

Answer (score -2):

You can have something like that :

```
class Parent
{
   public virtual Context GetContext()
   {
       return GetContextParentCall();
   }

   private Context GetContextParentCall()
   {
       return new Context(true);
   }

   public virtual GetData()
   {
       var context = GetContext();
       var result = Query(context);
       return result;
   }

   public string GetData2()
   {
       var context = GetContextParentCall();
       var result = Query(context);
       return result;
   }

}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the parent but in the child.